# Why is my soup obj empty?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get all the URLs for the class='profile-search-school-link' but cannot even get a soup object.

I do the following:

```
site = "http://www.geteducated.com/profiles/search/Computer%20Science%20%26%20IT&SS=Search%20by%20Subject%20%3E%20Computer%20Science%20%26%20IT/?start=15"

""" gets a list of the urls for the degree programs """
r = requests.get(site)
html_source = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source)

print(soup.prettify())
```

output:

```
<class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'> # print statement
[] # my depressingly empty soup
```

1. What's up with the code?  Link is not broken when I paste into my browser.
2. How do I get the URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about you but for me the link is broken - that may be your first problem ;)

I get a Error Code `500` response

---

hmm so it works after I first go to the base url without the ?start.

ahh I think it's because after you first go to the website it stores things in your local storage - e.g. cookies. Beautiful Soup cannot do that unless you enable cookies ;)

I suggest using [CookieLib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html)

Comment: It doesn't load on mine either. Could you take off the /?start=15. It works for me then.